# Question on relation between limit of sequence and that of its subsequence

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $\;f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^m\;$ be a bounded solution of the
>   pde $\;\Delta f=W_f(f)\;$ which satisfies $\;f(x_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$
>   as $\;x_1 \to +\infty\;$.
>
> If there exists a subsequence of $\;f\;$ , $\;f^k(x_1+y_1,x_2)\;$ that
>   converges uniformly in $\;\mathcal C^2_{loc} (\mathbb R^2;\mathbb
>  R^m)\;$ in a solution of the above pde, such that $\;f^k(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to
>  h(x_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;k \to +\infty\;$, then could I claim
>   $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$?

My professor used this argument in order to obtain the above:

" Since there exists a subsequence of $\;f\;$ , $\;f^k(x_1+y_1,x_2)\;$ that
 converges uniformly in $\;\mathcal C^2_{loc} (\mathbb R^2;\mathbb
 R^m)\;$ in a solution of the above pde, then the limit function should depend on $\;k\;$ in the sense that: $\;f^k(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to
 h^k(x_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;k \to +\infty\;$. Now if the limit of $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$ does exist, then it should hold that $\;h^k(x_1,x_2)\;$ is independent of the subsequence $\;f^k\;$ and so $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$"

However this explanation seemed a little weird to me. **Is the above fully true?**

As I see it, the key here is the assumption that the limit of $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2)\;$ exists. Hence the limits of the sequence and its subsequence must be the same, thus $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to h(x_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$

**Have I understood it right?** I would appreciate if somebody could ensure me if this is completely correct or fix my mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is $W_f$ here?

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos $\;W \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^m;\mathbb R_{+})\;$ and $\;W_f\;$ denotes $\;\frac{\partial W}{\partial f_i}\;\;\forall 1\le i \le m\;$